# Listing Facebook Open Graph Objects from an Application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

According to Facebook's Open Graph API Documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-api/), you should be able to list object's associated with your application with:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/app/objects/$OBJECT_TYPE?access_token=$APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

However, when I attempt to list my application's Open Graph Articles, with

```
https://graph.facebook.com/app/objects/article?access_token=$APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

I get an empty array. Additionally, I get an error on the Object Browser page (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/object-browser) stating:

```
There are no Object Types configured for this app.
```

I have added Open Graph as a product to the application and there are many objects that have been created with my Application using the fb:app_id meta tag as follows:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="MY_APP_ID">
```

Is there something else I am missing that needs to be done to associate an OG object with an application or enable Open Graph objects other than adding the fb:app_id meta tag to the page?

Comment: You can only read the objects that were _created_ via the Object API in the first place. Putting the meta tag into a website is something completely different.

Comment: @CBroe thanks.  Good to know since I looked all over for that information and couldn't find it.  The documentation definitely makes it sound like self-hosted OG Objects would be associated with the application and therefore available through the api.  Why else would there be an option to add the fb:app_id to the object?

Comment: For other purposes - share attribution, comment moderation, domain insights (not available any more), ...